# @date_default_timezone_get() silently crashes

Tags: php

I have the following test code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>
            Hi
    </p>
    <?php 
            if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_get')) {
                    echo "J";
                    $timezone = @date_default_timezone_get();
                    echo "K";
                    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
                    echo "L";
            }  
            phpinfo(); 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I retrieve it through my apparently working apache I get just:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>
        Hi
    </p>
    J
```

If I comment out the '$timezone = @date_default_timezone_get();' then I get a response with an error about '$timezone' not being defined and then the standard phpinfo() output.

All of the debugging options I've found thus far don't show me anything of interest in any log.

Running the script with php on the command line it gives no error either.

FYI: This is me attempting to figure out why my websvn suddenly stopped working, I've narrowed down the failure to this line and it fails in the sample code, so I'm feeling reasonably good about this other than why it just wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you keeping the `@` before the function call? It suppresses the error output which may be of help.

Also, what PHP version are you using? DateTime functions are only enabled by default since 5.2.0.

I wouldn't also exclude the possibility that even though `date_default_timezone_get()` function exists, it is not a standard one that comes with PHP, but something custom-made instead.

Comment: Haha, clearly I'm not a php dev. Removing the @ would have been useful :)

Answer (score 0):

After commenting out the call entirely in websvn I got a new error from another line:

> Timezone database is corrupt - this should never happen!

This error led me to investigate what was wrong with my timezone info and apparently all of files in /usr/share/zoneinfo/ had 640 permissions, changing them to 644 and the errors have gone.